# Gnome Terminal: font background shifted

Tags: gnome-terminal, zsh

The powerline fonts are somehow broken on my gnome terminal:
[image: here]

does anyone have a clue why this could happen?

I'm using oh-my-zsh and I'm scaling the interface to 2 because of my high resolution display.

Comment: What (regular) font do you use? Powerline is not a standalone font, only the addition of some symbols like the triangles. Looks to me that the problem is neither the background nor the powerline symbols, but the base font in general. Even the English letters are shifted upwards compared to their expected position, e.g. "h", "l" and "@" touch the very top of the emulator area. Can you try with other fonts?

Comment: @egmont I'm using "Monospace regular", but with a custom size. Changing the font doesn't make anything better, unfortunately: [see here](https://i.imgur.com/Ze4jgf9.png).
But it's true, all characters seem to be shifted upwards. I tried reinstalling powerline fonts, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: There's something really weird with your fonts. I'm using "Monospace" too and it looks very different to yours. Your "Monospace" and "Nimbus" look exactly the same, probably Courier is the actually font as far as I can tell. I have no idea what's wrong on your system, but I'd try to install more fonts, and then try out ones that actually look different.